# How do I make those nice summary boxes like Dispatch and SparseArray do?

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, elided-forms

`Dispatch` and `SparseArray` have nice output forms that summarise their contents:

[image: Example of Dispatch output]

The contents even manage to be retained fully on copy/paste. How can I make this happen for my own symbols?

Comment: Oh, now I find that this is a duplicate!

Answer (score 9):

If you want to make a nice neat way of displaying a thing with Head `head`, the following will work (thanks to Sjoerd):

```
head /: Format[b : head[a_Association]] := 
 RawBoxes[
  BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[
   "NiceHeadName",
   b, 
   Graphics3D[Cone[], ImageSize -> 20],
   {BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Summary 1: ", a["sum1"]}, StandardForm], 
    BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Summary 2: ", a["sum2"]}, StandardForm]}, 
   {BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Expanded thing 1: ", a["sumhidden1"]}, StandardForm], 
    BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Expanded thing 2: ", a["sumhidden2"]}, StandardForm], 
    BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Expanded thing 3: ", a["sumhidden3"]}, StandardForm]},
   StandardForm]
 ];
```

If you give a definition as

```
head[
 <| "sum1" -> 10, "sum2" -> "Hi!",
    "sumhidden1" -> 1, "sumhidden2" -> 2, "sumhidden3" -> Pi
 |>
]
```

then the output (shown twice, once non-expanded in the Out cell and once expanded in the next In cell) is:

[image: Nice output for head object]

Moreover, this object has the same `FullForm` as the original: you can copy and paste it, and it'll still work fine. In particular, though it appears to have Head `NiceHeadName`, it actually still has Head `head`, just as required.

Comment: Could you please tell me what role b plays here?

Comment: @chris If you `FullForm` the expression, the relevant chunk is `Format[Pattern[b, head[Pattern[a, Blank[Association]]]]]`. It's just a pattern name. See the docs for `Pattern`, and note that `b_` is shorthand for `b : _`.

Comment: What is the point of the `b` in ` "NiceHeadName",   b, ` ? It seems to lead to some recursions in some situation and I do not see its benefit?