# Adding Regularisation to Built-in Interpolation Function

Tags: performance-tuning, fitting, interpolation

tl;tr;  How to improve performance of [regularised](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10997/1089) `Interpolation`?

**Context**

Since Version 12, Mathematica now incorporates a range of (underrated IMHO) [regularisation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FitRegularization.html) methods to `Fit` and `FindFit`.

[image]

The option `FitRegularization` is particularly useful to regularise a fit,
i.e. allow the `BSpline` basis not to go through the data points but provide
a smoother fit. More generally these two functions also provide different  [NormFunction](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NormFunction.html), which specify what norm[residual] should be minimised when doing the fit, which is also useful and general.

> Hence I find it would be great that these two options be added
> to `Interpolation` transparently so that when interpolating,
> the option of not going *exactly* through the points can be controlled, e.g. if the purpose is to later differentiate the interpolation function.

**(fairly successful) Attempt**

Hence I have wrapped a new function, `RegularisedInterpolation`,  inspired by this (elegant) [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110210/1089)  by @J.M. which does the interpolation explicitly using `Fit` and therefore inherits these functionalities.

```
Clear[RegularisedInterpolation];
RegularisedInterpolation[dat_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{fspl, fb, sd, scpts, sk, var, dim, x, y, z , t},
  fspl = Interpolation[dat, Method -> "Spline", 
    FilterRules[{opt}, Options[Interpolation]]];
  If[Length[FilterRules[{opt}, Options[Fit]]] == 0, Return[fspl]];
  fb = First[Cases[fspl, _BSplineFunction, \[Infinity]]];
  {sd, scpts, sk} = fb /@ {"Degree", "ControlPoints", "Knots"};
  dim = Last@Dimensions[dat];
  var = Which[dim == 2, {x},
    dim == 3, {x, y}, dim == 4, {x, y, z}, dim == 5, {x, y, z, t}];
  Compile[var // Evaluate, 
   Fit[dat, 
      Flatten[Outer[Times, 
         Sequence @@ MapThread[
           Table[BSplineBasis[{#1, #2}, k - 1, #3], {k, #4}] &, {sd, 
            sk, var // Evaluate, Dimensions[scpts]}]]] // Evaluate, 
      var // Evaluate,
      FilterRules[{opt}, Options[Fit]]
      ] // Chop // Evaluate]
  ]
```

It works as expected (in arbitrary dimension) as I will illustrate, *up to 3 glitchs* for which I am seeking help.

**Validation**

---

Let's first look at one dimensional data

```
 dat1 = Table[{i, Sin[i^2]}, {i, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/64}] // N;
 dat1 = dat1 /. {x_, y_} :> {x, y (1 + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.05]])};
```

First note that by default it does a standard interpolation.

```
g1 = RegularisedInterpolation[dat1];
```

Then I can add options from `Fit` and from `Interpolation`

```
gr = RegularisedInterpolation[dat1, 
FitRegularization -> {"Curvature", 10^-0.5}, InterpolationOrder -> 3]
```

If I plot the 2 Interpolations (pink and yellow) they look fairly similar

```
Show[Plot[{Sin[x^2], gr[x], g1[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}], ListPlot[dat1], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

but when I differentiate it the regularised version (in pink) remains closer to the  un-noised data (in red), when compared to the (yellow) interpolation.

```
Plot[{2 x Cos[x^2], D[gr[x], x], D[g1[x], x]} // Evaluate, {x, 0,  2 Pi}]
```

[image]

This is why I believe regularised interpolation is useful (even though it
is a bit of a contradiction in terms).

---

Let's now look at two or three dimensional data

```
dat2 = Flatten[
Table[{i, j, Sin[i*j]}, {i, 0, 5, 0.5}, {j, 0, 5, 0.5}], 1] // N;
g2 = RegularisedInterpolation[dat2]
g2r = RegularisedInterpolation[dat2, 
  FitRegularization -> {"Curvature", 10^-0.5}]
pl2 = Plot3D[{D[g2[x, y], x],D[g2r[x, y], x] } // Evaluate, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4], PlotPoints -> 20, PlotRange -> All];
```

[image]

Note the difference between the two curves: one is slightly smoother than the other.

Similarly in 3D

```
dat3 = Flatten[
 Table[{i, j, k, Sin[i*j*k]}, {i, 0, 2, 0.5}, {j, 0, 2, 0.5}, {k, 0, 2, 0.5}], 2];
g3 = RegularisedInterpolation[dat3, 
 FitRegularization -> {"Curvature", 10^-7.5}];
```

The regularised fit does not go exactly through the 3D data (as it should)

```
dat3 - Flatten[
 Table[{x, y, z, g3[x, y, z]}, {x, 0, 2, 0.5}, {y, 0, 2, 0.5}, {z,
    0, 2, 0.5}], 2] // Transpose // Last // ListPlot
```

[image]

While I am fairly happy with the result, I still have 3 issues

---

**Questions**

I have in fact three questions:

> 1. The code, while working complains about this

```
Experimental`NumericalFunction::dimsl: {y} given in {x,y} 
 should be a list of dimensions for a particular argument.
```

I have no idea what the issue is. Does anyone?

> 2. The performance is not very good in 2 and 3 dimensions when evaluating the fit (not when doing the inversion).

```
pl2 = Plot3D[D[g2[x, y], x] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4], PlotPoints -> 20, 
    PlotRange -> All]; // Timing
```

(* {0.179184,Null} *)

```
pl2r = Plot3D[D[g2r[x, y], x] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4], PlotPoints -> 20, 
    PlotRange -> All]; // Timing
```

(*  {2.12889,Null} *)

It may be  because the plotting routine refine on  the boundaries of the  splines? Would you know how to get back to `Interpolation`'s native performance?

> 3. I would ideally prefer that the result of the fit show the same kind of wrapper as Interpolation  (specifying the boundary of the interpolation)

I.e. it should return something like this:

[image]

Do you have any idea how to 'hide' information in this manner?
Through associations??

Thank you for your help.
I am hoping that many people will find this generic wrapper useful eventually.

---

**Comments/ improvements**

- It was drawn to my attention by @Henkik that the formulation is semantically incorrect since interpolation is meant to refer to 'going through the points'. The present function could/should be called `BSplineRegularisedFit`. On the other hand
  it has the same structure as `Interpolation`, and could seamlessly be integrated
  to the built-in function by simply increasing the number of options.
- @Kuba pointed out that [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77658/how-to-create-expanding-summary-boxes-like-the-ones-displayed-for-interpolatingf) and  [that](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99914/1089) question addresses the wrapping issue. He also pointed out that

  Needs@"GeneralUtilities`"
  PrintDefinitions@InterpolatingFunction

yields  the wrapper for InterpolatingFunction.

- This [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176375/1089) shows how it could be generalised to un evenly sampled data as well. Here the main advantage is to inherit all the nice properties of Interpolation.
- It might be useful to be able to impose extra knots at the boundary of the domain?

**Complement**

To illustrate the benefit of regularisation let's add a glitch to the data
and see how different penalty operate while changing the method and its amplitude.

```
Table[Plot[
   Table[RegularisedInterpolation[dat1, 
       FitRegularization -> {meth, 10^i}][x], {i, -2, 2, 0.5}] // 
    Evaluate,
   {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {meth, {"Curvature", "Variation", "TotalVariation", 
    "LASSO"}}] // Partition[#, 2] &
```

[image]

---

To illustrate the issue with the end point let us consider the successive derivative of the sine wave

```
dat1 = Table[{i, Sin[3 i]}, {i, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/8}] // N;
Clear[g]; 
g[x_] = RegularisedInterpolation[dat1, 
   FitRegularization -> {"Curvature", 10^-9.5}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 12][x];
Table[Plot[D[{g[x], Sin[3 x]}, {x, i}] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
  , {i, 0, 5}] // Partition[#, 2] &
```

[image]

The match at the edge becomes worse with order of the derivative.

Comment: I apologize for having been too harsh. I did not mean to be. I admit that I lost contenance over the frustration. Still, somebody who says "dog" all the time but actually means to say "duck" must not be surprised that their audience is confused. I am pretty sure that the term interpolation is _always_ used in the same way in all discliplines (if correctly used): It denotes methods that reproduce the input data _exactly_. In contrast, for a fit ones is satisfied with reproducing the input _approximately_ and typically focuses on simplicity or regularity of the model.

Comment: Sometimes, interpolation is used for fitting, but Runge's phenomenon tells us that this is actually not a good idea. So in some sense, interpolation mathods can be considered a subset of fitting methods. But the other inclusion is definitely not true: A fit that does not reproduce the input is by definition not an interpolation.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher in these troubled times I suggest https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lqnxP_2zyDc

Comment: *rofl* Yeah, good idea. That's what every psychotherapist would subscribe... ^^

Comment: I must say don't understand the focus on linguistic in upvoting comments. The relevant issue should be,' is this function useful or not?' not wether is it legitimate to give the function a name which still contains the word Interpolation, for which there is some  logic: adding some options to the interpolation function so that derivatives remain as smooth as they should be.

Comment: By "performance" do you mean "goodness-of-fit" or "speed of calculations" ?  Or both?  If "goodness-of-fit", how are you characterizing goodness-of-fit AND what value of goodness-of-fit is adequate for your needs?

Comment: FWIW: I would term this a "regularized piecewise polynomial fit", but that is understandably a mouthful to say. In any event: I don't have my copy beside me, but I recall regularization was discussed in Piegl and Tiller's book.

Comment: @J.M. thanks!  Since I borrowed your code do you have a suggestion for this very related question? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/219076/1089

Comment: Like I said, I (fuzzily) recall that Piegl and Tiller discussed this, but their algorithm was pretty elaborate (I think it also did cross-validation and other fancy things). So, I am not sure this is something easily done in a few lines. I'll look into it when I get a chance.

Comment: Strongly related: [`QuantileRegression`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162145/280) and [`QuantileRegressionFit`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114907/280) by @AntonAntonov.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regarding item 2/

> A possible  performance improvement (which **still not scale very well**, so *please* feel free to provide better answers!).
>     is achieved by re-ordering the `PieceWise` function behind the spline.

Let us start with some 1D data and find the Regularised Interpolation

```
dat1 = Table[{i, Sin[3 i]}, {i, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/32}] // N;
Clear[g]; g[x_] = RegularisedInterpolation[dat1, 
  FitRegularization -> {"Variation", 10^-3.5}, InterpolationOrder -> 3][x];
```

Then If I  reorder the `PieceWise` function

```
tt = PiecewiseExpand /@ g[x] // Simplify;
tt1 = Sort[Select[tt[[1]], FreeQ[#[[2]], Equal] &], #1[[2, 1]] < #2[[2, 1]] &] /. 
   Less -> LessEqual;
g2 = Compile[x, Piecewise[tt1] // Evaluate]
```

then the performance when plotting is quite improved:

```
Plot[g2[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]; // Timing
```

(* 0.024671` *)

over

```
Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]; // Timing
```

(* 0.296903 *)

---

In 2D it works as well (but the `Simplify` takes a little while)

```
dat2 = Flatten[
    Table[{i, j, Sin[i*j]}, {i, 0, 5, 0.5}, {j, 0, 5, 0.5}], 1] // N;
Clear[g]; g[x_, y_] = RegularisedInterpolation[dat2, 
    FitRegularization -> {"Curvature", 10^-2.5}][x, y];
tt = PiecewiseExpand /@ g[x, y] // Simplify;
tt1 = Sort[Select[tt[[1]],FreeQ[#[[2]], 
     Equal] &], #1[[2, 1]] < #2[[2, 1]] &] /. Less -> LessEqual;
g2 = Compile[{x, y}, Piecewise[tt1] // Evaluate]
```

Then

```
  Plot3D[g2[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4], PlotPoints -> 20, PlotRange -> All]
```

(* 0.268701 *)

is 16 times faster than

```
Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4],
     PlotPoints -> 20, PlotRange -> All]; // Timing
```

(* 8.43557 *)

So one can add a option `PiecewiseSimplify`  to `RegularisedInterpolation`, see the full code below.

---

Regarding item 3, following closely this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99914/1089) the trick is to define a new head,  `RegularisedInterpolatingFunction` and return an Association which contains more  than just the compiled code (Domain, Regularisation method and  parameter etc..). One adds the rule that

```
  RegularisedInterpolatingFunction[a_Association][b__] := a["code"][b]
```

i.e. that the Object applied to some data or symbol `b` applies the Piecewise code `a["code"]`. Then we can use BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox` BoxForm `MakeSummaryItem` to wrap a  Summary box around the `RegularisedInterpolationFunction` object.

```
 gr = RegularisedInterpolation[dat1, FitRegularization -> {"Curvature", 10^-0.5}]
```

[image]

which can be expanded as

[image]

---

Finally I have added `RegularisedListInterpolation` which 
as `ListInterpolation` takes tables as arguments as 
in

```
  dat=Table[Sin[x^2+y]//N,{x,1,5,0.5},{y,1,5,0.5}];
  gr = RegularisedListInterpolation[dat, 
     FitRegularization -> {"Curvature", 10^-0.5}];
```

It should work in dimensions 1 to 4.

---

*The full code now reads*

```
ClearAll[RegularisedInterpolation, RegularisedListInterpolation,
RegularisedInterpolatingFunction];

RegularisedInterpolation::usage="Works like Interpolation but also inherits
options from Fit including FitRegularization.
 Example: \n dat1=Table[{x,Sin[x ]},{x,0,2,0.2}];
gr1=RegularisedInterpolation[dat1,FitRegularization->{\"Curvature\",0.01}];
dat2=Table[{x,y,Sin[x y]},{x,0,2,0.2},{y,0,2,0.2}]//Flatten[#,1]&;
gr2=RegularisedInterpolation[dat2
,FitRegularization->{\"Curvature\",0.01}];";

 RegularisedListInterpolation::usage="Works
like ListInterpolation but also inherits options from Fit including
FitRegularization.
 Example: \n dat1=Table[Sin[x ],{x,0,2,0.2}];
       gr1=RegularisedListInterpolation[dat1,FitRegularization->{\"Curvature\",0.01}];
dat2=Table[Sin[x y],{x,0,2,0.2},{y,0,2,0.2}];
gr2=RegularisedListInterpolation[dat2 ,FitRegularization->{\"Curvature\",0.01}]\
;";


Options[RegularisedInterpolation] = 
  Union[{PiecewiseSimplify -> False}, Options[Interpolation],
   Options[Fit]];
RegularisedInterpolation[dat_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{fspl, fb, sd, scpts, sk, var, dim, x, y, z, t, tt},
  fspl = Interpolation[dat, Method -> "Spline", 
    FilterRules[{opt}, Options[Interpolation]]];
  If[Length[FilterRules[{opt},Options[Fit]]]==0, Return[fspl]];
  fb = First[Cases[fspl, _BSplineFunction, \[Infinity]]];
  {sd, scpts, sk} = fb /@ {"Degree", "ControlPoints", "Knots"};
  dim = Last@Dimensions[If[Depth[dat] > 3, 
      Flatten /@ dat, dat]] - 1;
  var = Which[dim == 1, {x},
    dim == 2, {x, y}, dim == 3, {x, y, z}, dim == 4, {x, y, z, t}];
  tt = Compile[var // Evaluate, 
    Fit[If[Depth[dat] > 3, Flatten /@ dat, dat], 
       Flatten[Outer[Times, 
          Sequence @@ 
           MapThread[
            Table[BSplineBasis[{#1, #2}, k - 1, #3], {k, #4}] &, {sd, 
             sk, var // Evaluate, Dimensions[scpts]}]]] // Evaluate, 
       var // Evaluate,
       FilterRules[{opt}, Options[Fit]]
       ] // Chop // Evaluate];
  RegularisedInterpolatingFunction[<|
    "dimension" -> dim,
    "method" -> OptionValue[ FitRegularization],
    "order" -> OptionValue[InterpolationOrder],
    "domain" -> Most@( MinMax /@ Transpose[dat]), 
    "code" -> If[OptionValue[PiecewiseSimplify],
       tt = PiecewiseExpand /@ tt @@ var // Simplify;
       Compile[var // Evaluate, tt// Evaluate, 
        CompilationTarget -> "C"],
       tt] // Evaluate|>]
  ]

RegularisedListInterpolation[dat_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] :=RegularisedInterpolation[ 
   Flatten[MapIndexed[Flatten[{#2, #1}] &, dat, {TensorRank@dat}], 
    TensorRank[dat] - 1], opt];


RegularisedInterpolatingFunction /: 
  Format[b : RegularisedInterpolatingFunction[a_Association]] := 
  RawBoxes[BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[
    "RegularisedInterpolatingFunction", "", 
    Graphics3D[Cone[], 
     ImageSize -> 
      20], {BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Dimensions: ", a["dimension"]}, 
      StandardForm], 
     BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Domain: ", MatrixForm@a["domain"]}, 
      StandardForm]}, {BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Regularisation \
method: ", MatrixForm@a["method"]}, StandardForm],
     BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Interpolation order: ", 
       a["order"] // Shallow}, StandardForm],
     BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Compiled Code: ", a["code"]}, 
      StandardForm]}, StandardForm]];    



RegularisedInterpolatingFunction[a_Association][b__] := 
 a[b] /; (b == "dimension" || b == "order" || b == "domain" || 
    b == "method")
RegularisedInterpolatingFunction[a_Association][b__] := a["code"][b]
```

With this code we have 2 new functions:

```
 ?RegularisedInterpolation
```

[image]

```
  ?RegularisedListInterpolation
```

[image]

**Concluding remark**

The present implementation still remains quite sub optimal, mainly because the `Fit` does not scale well, see this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/219076/1089). It could be enhanced by adding resampling (of the knots wrt data points) and Automated choice of regularisation (via GCV).

Comment: I know you're not too interested in linguistics, but maybe `RegularisedInterpolatingFunction` would be consistent with `Interpolation` -> `InterpolatingFunction`?  Actually, could the result of `RegularisedInterpolation` be an `InterpolatingFunction`?

Comment: @ChrisK you are absolutely right (twice). I wish `RegularisedInterpolation` Could simply be an `InterpolatingFunction` so I would not have to write special wrapper. And I will rename  RegularisedInterpolationFunction to RegularisedInterpolatingFunction

Answer (score 2):

The function [`CurveToBSplineFunction`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CurveToBSplineFunction/) Does something closely related:

```
dat1 = Table[{i, Sin[i^2]}, {i, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/64}] // N;
dat1 = dat1 /. {x_, y_} :> {x, 
     y (1 + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.05]])};
pl1 = ListPlot[dat1, PlotStyle -> Red];
g = ResourceFunction["CurveToBSplineFunction"][dat1, 1];
Show[pl1, ParametricPlot[g[u], {u, 0, 1}]]
```

[image]

And by changing the control parameter:

```
g = ResourceFunction["CurveToBSplineFunction"][dat1, 20];
Show[pl1, ParametricPlot[g[u], {u, 0, 1}]]
```

[image]

Note that `CurveToBSplineFunction` has a few useful options:

```
Options[ResourceFunction["CurveToBSplineFunction"]]
```

(*  {CurveClosed->False,FillGaps->True,AssignWeights->False,DuplicateNodes->False} *)

All credits goes to Alexey Popkov who wrote this function!