# Improving speed performance of 'Fit' with BSplines?

Tags: performance-tuning, fitting, splines

#### Context

In the context of this (vaguely controversial)  [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/218764/1089), 
 I am stumbling into a performance issue with `Fit`.

Let me illustrate on fitting a set  of BSplines to set of 64 data points:

```
dat = Table[{i, Sin[i^2]}, {i, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/32}] // N;
fspl = Interpolation[dat, Method -> "Spline"];
fb = First[Cases[fspl, _BSplineFunction, ∞]];
{sd, scpts, sk} = fb /@ {"Degree", "ControlPoints", "Knots"};
func = Flatten[Outer[Times, Sequence @@ MapThread[
Table[BSplineBasis[{#1, #2},k-1, #3], {k, #4}] &, {sd, sk, {x}, Dimensions[scpts]}]]];
fit = Fit[dat, func,x, FitRegularization -> {"Curvature", 1.}]; // Timing
```

(* 0.008626  *)

```
Plot[fit, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

But if I now ask say for 1024 points

```
dat = Table[{i, Sin[i^2]}, {i, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/512}] // N;
fspl = Interpolation[dat, Method -> "Spline"];
fb = First[Cases[fspl, _BSplineFunction, ∞]];
{sd, scpts, sk} = fb /@ {"Degree", "ControlPoints", "Knots"};
func = Flatten[Outer[Times, Sequence @@ MapThread[
Table[BSplineBasis[{#1, #2}, k-1, #3], {k, #4}] &, {sd, sk, {x}, Dimensions[scpts]}]]];
fit = Fit[dat, func,x, FitRegularization -> {"Curvature", 1.}]; // Timing
```

(* 5.83293 *)

It takes  dramatically much longer!
(and it get much worse with higher sampling)

#### Question

> Is is possible to improve the performance of `Fit` on this specific problem?

Thank you for your help.

I am aware that I could ask for less BSplines but...

Comment: How close a fit do you need?  Suppose the root mean square error is a satisfactory measure of goodness-of-it.  With `SeedRandom[12345]`, 1024 gets you an RMSE of 0.000093, 512 points get you 0.00068, 256 points gets you 0.0049, 128 points gets you 0.039, and 64 points gets you 0.231.   64 points is almost certainly an inadequate number of points.  But what is adequate?  Is it "I'll know it when I see it" ?

Comment: @JimB sorry for the ambiguity. I meant to say it takes forever. The fit seems good enough.