# Interpolation not working

Tags: interpolation

This is probably a very silly question but I am trying to use `Interpolation` for the following data:

```
  data={{0.965251, 0.}, {3.0888, 0.}, {5.98456, 0.}, {9.26641, 0.}, {12.5483,
   0.}, {15.8301, 0.}, {18.1467, 0.}, {21.8147, 0.}, {26.2548, 
  0.}, {30.695, 1.12676}, {33.3977, 1.69014}, {36.8726, 
  2.53521}, {39.3822, 3.38028}, {42.8571, 3.94366}, {45.7529, 
  5.35211}, {48.8417, 6.76056}, {51.5444, 8.73239}, {54.0541, 
  10.9859}, {55.7915, 13.2394}, {58.1081, 16.9014}, {59.0734, 
  19.1549}, {61.0039, 22.8169}, {62.1622, 26.4789}, {63.3205, 
  30.4225}, {64.2857, 34.3662}, {65.0579, 38.3099}, {65.8301, 
  42.8169}, {66.7954, 47.8873}, {67.3745, 53.8028}, {68.3398, 
  60.5634}, {68.9189, 65.6338}, {69.112, 71.5493}, {69.6911, 
  78.0282}, {70.2703, 84.507}, {70.6564, 88.4507}, {70.6564, 
  92.3944}, {71.4286, 97.1831}, {72.5869, 100.563}, {73.7452, 
  98.3099}, {74.5174, 92.6761}, {74.7104, 87.3239}, {75.0965, 
  82.2535}, {75.2896, 77.4648}, {75.6757, 72.1127}, {76.0618, 
  63.3803}, {76.6409, 54.6479}, {77.027, 47.3239}, {77.4131, 
  40.}, {78.3784, 35.2113}, {78.5714, 29.8592}, {80.1158, 
  24.2254}, {81.4672, 22.2535}, {82.8185, 19.7183}, {84.3629, 
  18.8732}, {87.2587, 18.5915}, {91.6988, 18.8732}, {94.5946, 
  18.5915}, {98.2626, 18.3099}, {100., 18.3099}, {120., 18.3099}};

Interpolation[data]
```

but for some reason it does not Interpolated correctly. If I plot the data it looks fine. Can someone tell me why `Interpolation` doesn't correctly fit this data?

I get the following errro message:

InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {0.00245143} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.

Comment: Probably has something to do with the error message, no?  Or you don't get one?

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes! I just updated the question for you to see the error that I get

Comment: Hmm, I get "Interpolation::inddp: The point 70.6564` in dimension 1 is duplicated."

Comment: I  was getting that too before. But the problem is that I don't really see any problem with the data that will make interpolation not to work

Comment: To answer the question about your error message, show the code that produced it.  Mine could be due to the code for `data` being incomplete (the numbers are rounded to six digits).  One can see by eye that there are two points with 70.6564 in the first coordinate.

Comment: Above is exactly as I put it. I just put `Interpolation[data]`. If you put `ListLinePlot[data]` you can see that the data plots very different than the interpolation function fitting

Comment: Sometimes Mathematica error messages are inscrutable, but here both are clear.  `Interpolation::inddp: The point 70.6564 in dimension 1 is duplicated.` means you have two values for `70.6564` in `data`.  Either nudge one by a small amount or drop one.  `InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {0.00245143} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.` is more a warning than an error: your data start at `0.965251` so when you ask for `0.00245143`, Mathematica needs to extrapolate.  It might work out fine, it might be catastrophically wrong.

Comment: @ChrisK how can I fix it then? I have tried removing one of the values with 70.6564 and it still does not fit it correctly or similar to when you plot the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what happens when I drop the second value for 70.6564.

```
Show[
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black],
 Plot[Evaluate@Interpolation[data][x], {x, 0, 120}, PlotRange -> All]
]
```

[image]

If those wiggles bother you, use linear interpolation instead:

```
Show[
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black],
 Plot[Evaluate@Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x], {x, 0, 120}, PlotRange -> All]
 ]
```

[image]

Or if you don't need the InterpolatingFunction to go exactly through the data, try [this approach to regularised Interpolation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/218764/adding-regularisation-to-built-in-interpolation-function).

Comment: Awesome! Christ thank you very much for your suggestion and also about the wiggles! This is what I wanted! I really appreciate it