# NeumannValue nonlinear pde?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

Inspired by the highly interesting question [Solving Burger's equation with NDSolve at large time](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267890/solving-burgers-equation-with-ndsolve-at-large-time/267928#267928) I'll try to understand Finite-Element-solution for nonlinear pde in more detail:

Burger pde

$u_t(x,t)+u(x,t) u_x(x,t)=0$

with initial condition  $u(x,0)=x+1$
is solved by

$u(x,t)=\frac{x+1}{t+1}$

```
0==Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t]  + u[x, t] Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]  
/. u ->Function[{x, t}, (x + 1)/(t + 1) ] (*True*)
```

`Method-FiniteElements` is able to approximate this solution quite well

```
U = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[0, 1][u][x,t]  +  
u[x, t] Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]  == 
NeumannValue[0, True], 
u[x, 0] == 1 + x}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0,5}];


Plot[{U[x, #] , (1 + x)/(1 + #)} // Evaluate, {x, 0, 1},AxesLabel -> {"x", "U[x,t]"},PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Dashed, Red}} ] &[1]
```

[image]

To enforce `MethodOfLines`and `FiniteElement` I used `NeumannValue` on the right hand side of the pde in `NDSolveValue`

**My question**

How is `NeumannValue` defined in this nonlinear case?

I expected something like `u[x,t]^2/2` or `D[u[x,t]^2/2,x]`  , but expressions don't vanish at `x==0,x==1`. Same with `D[u[x,t] ,x]`.

Thanks!

Comment: Happy to see someone asking this. (I noticed there seems to be an issue when answering the linked question but is too lazy to post a question. ) In principle we can use [``NDSolve`FEM`GetInactivePDE``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225841/1871) to determine the `NeumannValue`, but obviously ``NDSolve`FEM`GetInactivePDE`` isn't working properly in this case. (The output is `u[x] u'[x] + Derivative[1, 0][u][t, x]`! ) user21 should be able to answer this. Let's wait for a moment :) .

Comment: @xzczd Thanks, nice to meet you again today. I'm looking forward to the answer of user21

Comment: NeumannValue is defined in relation to anything that is in the Div part of a PDE. There is no such part in this PDE and as such the `NeumannValue` is not defined. As a side note, note that the coefficient could be parsed as convection coefficient (factor * u') or as a reaction coefficient (factor * u) or possibly also a once size fits all nonlinear right hands side f) but none of those have a relation to a divergence, which is needed for a NeumannValue.

Comment: @user21 Thank you for your detailled answer! That means in this case `FiniteElement` is some kind of galerkin method?

Comment: @user21 Isn't `D[u[x,t]^2,x]` such a div-part you mention?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question: There is no `D[u[x,t]^2,x]` in the equation. Even if there were, why would it relate to `Div[{u[x,t]},{x}]`. If you want that in the equation, you'd need to specify that with Inactive[Div][{u[x,t]},{x}]` and then you'd have something to relate the NeumannValue to.

Comment: @user21 Thanks. I transformed the second part in the pde `u[x, t]Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]`  to `D[u[x,t]^2,x]/2`

Comment: @user21 Any comment about the output of ``NDSolve`FEM`GetInactivePDE``?

Comment: @xzczd, the only thing that can a bit to a surprise was that some components had the `t` in them and some not. It looked like the reconstruction per se worked. Ultimately, if one want to know how it was parsed then one would need to look at the coefficients. If you look at this: {state} = 
  NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t] + 
      u[x, t] Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t] == NeumannValue[0, True], 
    u[x, 0] == 1 + x}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 5}];
pdecd["LoadCoefficients"] you will find that everything has been parsed into the load coefficient. Which is valid solution,I think

Comment: @xzczd, do you have anything specific that you have doubts about?

Comment: @user21 OK. The main doubt I had is, the FEM formal PDE isn't based on the conservative form $∂_x(u^2/2)$, but the solution obeys the conservation law well . (We see in the linked question `TensorProductGrid` doesn't work well when the discretization isn't based on the conservation law. ) But after a second thought, I notice when artificial viscosity is added, we don't need conservation law **in principle**. Probably it's because the ODE (DAE?) solver has done a better job when `FiniteElement` is chosen.

Comment: @user21 Where can I find information about `pdecd["LoadCoefficients"]` ?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, `FEMDocumentation/ref/PDECoefficientData` and related functions.

Comment: @user21 Thank you, I know the documentation but didn't find special function  `pdecd` there...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, now I see the issue, for some reason not everything got copied over.... here you go: `pdecd = state["FiniteElementData"]["PDECoefficientData"];
pdecd["LoadCoefficients"]`

Comment: @user21 Fine, now it works , thanks